# Multiple navigation with tabbar

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iPhone application using iPhone SDK 3.0. I need to use tabbar control along with navigation control. I also want to include a scrollview on the top of all views.Which contains a few number of buttons.These buttons are used to navigate to particular views. Tabbar contains 4 items. Total number views is about 8. So we can navigate to 4 of the views using tabbar as well as buttons on the top. The remaining 4 views can be accessed by using the buttons on the top only. I just created the  tabbar and able to navigate to particular views using tabbar buttons as well as buttons on the top. But I couldnt able to navigate to other views, views that are not in tabbar controllers array. So please tell me how can I implement this feature?

Thanx in advance,
Syam S
iPhone Devr.

Comment: Perhaps you could link us to a sketch of the UI you're trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

u want to navigate your remaining 4 view right? U can navigate that view using tabbar button also? when u creating an button on tabbar set the property [button setTag:Your number];
and when clicking on that button , at that check tag of sender and take a corresponding action.

let me know is this work or not?

Comment: But I dont want to display the remaining buttons as tabbar items. I just want it to display the four buttons on the top of view along with the tabbar items. In which there is a horizontal scrollview, which consists the whole buttons.  I want to navigate to the view while clicking on the buttons in the scrollview. I need to know the code snippet to navigate to view, which is not a tabbar item.

Comment: If it is possible to hide the buttons on the tabbar then it is easey. I mean remaining 4 buttons